# Changing text color in html doesen't work

Tags: html, css, colors

I'm trying to change the text color in a menu, I have tried the color tag and the text-decoration-color tag, but neither of them work. Here is what I am working on, in CSS

```css
#meny {
  position: absolute;
  top: 201px;
  left: 290px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 201px;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: smaller;
  color: #cccccc !important;
}
#meny a {
  line-height: 50px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Markveien legesenter</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="medic.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link href="stil.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <img src="del2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="bilde">
    <img src="del1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="meny"> <a href="#">HJEM</a><a href="#">OM OSS</a><a href="#">SLIK BESTILLER DU</a><a href="#">INFORMASJON</a><a href="#">LENKER</a> 
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Should `meny` be `menu`?

Comment: If you inspect the element in the browser you can see the css rules that affect it. See if something has precedence over these rules. If `meny` is a class name it needs a `. ` in front. If it's an id then you need a `#`. If it's actually a menu tag you need to update accordingly.

Comment: Please show your html

Comment: @Mik_A :

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Markveien legesenter</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="medic.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="stil.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"><img src="del2.jpg"></div>
        <div id="bilde"><img src="del1.jpg"></div>
        <div id="meny">
            <a href="#">HJEM</a><a href="#">OM OSS</a><a href="#">SLIK BESTILLER DU</a><a href="#">INFORMASJON</a><a href="#">LENKER</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: sorry I don't know how to make it show like in the top post

Comment: @unaml You can click on the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40495163/edit) button towards the bottom of your question and add that in.

Comment: a have it's own default color, you should reset the color on the link via color:#ccc or color:inherit ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the color of a, but you are putting the color on the container:

```
#meny a {
  line-height: 50px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ccc; /*add color here*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also reset color for the links:*(as i commented earlier :) )*

```css
#meny {
  position: absolute;
  top: 201px;
  left: 290px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 201px;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: smaller;
  color: #cccccc !important;
}
#meny a {
  color:inherit;
  line-height: 50px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Markveien legesenter</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="medic.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link href="stil.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <img src="del2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="bilde">
    <img src="del1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="meny"> <a href="#">HJEM</a><a href="#">OM OSS</a><a href="#">SLIK BESTILLER DU</a><a href="#">INFORMASJON</a><a href="#">LENKER</a> 
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```